# Drawing family trees with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tree, family-tree

I'm searching for tutorials on how to draw a family tree with WPF (and C#).

Something like http://www.myheritage.nl/FP/family-tree.php?s=65040841 or Family.Show but for a complete beginner. Family.Show is a bit too complex to start. I don't want to implement external controls but instead I want to learn how to write them myself.

So I need to know everything like: how to draw the items, what the algorithms are to position/draw all elements, etc... but I could not find any beginners tutorial on this with WPF.

I hope somebody could help me.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Family.Show:

> http://www.vertigo.com/familyshow.aspx

Comment: Well I'm searching something that is good for a beginner. Family.Show is a bit complex to start with...